# Jqgrid Dropdown not showing in Internet explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jqgrid

I have used jqgrid in ACE admin theme, everything is working fine in Internet Explorer except dropdown, i have also tried to change the compatible mode setting in IE, but there is no any change.
Only dropdown is not showing properly, other things are working perfect.
So how can i solve this problem.
Here i have attach screen shot, how its looks/
Please help. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help.

```
$("#Dropdownlist").click(function (event) {
if ($(this).val() != "") {
    event.preventDefault();
    // do something
}
});


$("#Dropdownlist").keydown(function (event) {
var code = event.keyCode || event.which;
if (code == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // do something
}
});
```